# Call a trigger in anonymous window

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement like if the candidate is also a lead, then in leads i have to insert a flag field. this i have done for the records which were newly inserted.

now for the existing records i have to update the field value with a flag. for that i have to run my trigger in anonymous window.
may i know how should i call trigger in anonymous window.

below is my class and trigger,

```
public class leadclass {

    public static void methodconcatenate(list<lead> newleadlist){
       // list<lead> updateleadlist;
        string fullname;
        map<string, candidate__c> candidatemap = new map<string, candidate__c>();

        for(lead l:newleadlist){
            if(l.firstname != null && l.lastname != null){
                fullname= l.firstname+ ' ' +l.lastname;
            }
        }
        for(candidate__c c : [select id, name from candidate__c where name=:fullname]){
            candidatemap.put(fullname,c);
        }

        for(lead l :newleadlist){
            if(candidatemap != null && !candidatemap.isempty() && candidatemap.containskey(l.firstname+ ' ' +l.lastname))
            l.candidate__c = candidatemap.get(l.firstname+ ' ' +l.lastname).id;
           // updateleadlist.add(l);
        }
       // update updateleadlist;
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    leadclass.methodconcatenate(trigger.new);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot call a trigger directly, either you can call handler methods or you can perform the action on which you want to test the trigger, suppose you want to check for insert trigger, you can insert the record for that object from Anonymous window.

If you insert lead from Anonymous window, the system will run all triggers for leads.

2. You need to compile a list of a full name instead of a single string variable.

   ```
   List<String> fullNameList = new List<String>(); // creating new list
   for(lead l:newleadlist){
       if(l.firstname != null && l.lastname != null){
           fullNameList.add(l.firstname+ ' ' +l.lastname);
       }
   }
   ```
3. You are querying just a single candidate, instead, call query all from the `fullnamelist`.

> Beware if you have enabled middle name for lead, this query will not
>   work as you are not considering `middlename` in the `fullnamelist`.

so your query will be

```
for(candidate__c c : [select id, name from candidate__c where name in :fullnamelist]){
     candidatemap.put(c.name,c);
}
```

4. No need to update leads separately as you are using before triggers.

[Refer Apex triggers Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)

[Refer Apex triggers Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a trigger directly, so the easiest way for you would be to create your own list of leads, pass it through your method, then perform the update.

e.g.

```
List<Lead> myLeads = [SELECT candidate__c, FirstName, LastName FROM Lead FOR UPDATE LIMIT 50000];

leadclass.methodconcatenate(myLeads);

update myLeads;
```

You'll need to work out what `where` clause to use for your SOQL query, otherwise this will attempt to update all the Leads in the system.

Comment: hey thanks, what will be the case if there were 53K records. how will i update for those recors

Comment: @iswaryasekar in exec anonymous - you can only do dml on up to 10000 recs and even then are subject to other limits like cpu time; my recommendation is to use data loader

Comment: Is it possible to write a batch class ?

Comment: @iswaryasekar It's possible, but you'd be much better off doing a data load as per cropredy's comment.  Just export all your candidates and do a vlookup in excel

Comment: but in lead i have only 2100 records and in candidates 53K records were there. how to match all of them. when i run the code for leads, its updating only for few records which is also a candidate.